# Converting a Pyside qt4 script to pyside2 qt5: where are my imports failing?

Tags: python, pyside, maya, pyside2

I'm trying to convert an old Maya python script to Maya 2017. In 2017 they made some changes including switching from PySide to PySide 2 and Qt4 to Qt5. I have no experience with either of these libraries or even python.

The first thing I did was try to run it through pyqt4topyqt5 with no necessary changes detected.

I believe the core functionality of the script is the same in both version however the GUI loading is failing because of these changes. The original script importing the libraries is the following:

```
import shiboken
from PySide import QtGui
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI
from cStringIO import StringIO
import pysideuic
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

def get_maya_window():

    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if ptr is not None:
        return shiboken.wrapInstance(long(ptr), QtGui.QMainWindow)

def load_ui_type(ui_file):

    parsed = xml.parse(ui_file)
    widget_class = parsed.find('widget').get('class')
    form_class = parsed.find('class').text
    with open(ui_file,'r') as f:
        o = StringIO()
        frame = {}

        pysideuic.compileUi(f, o, indent = 0)
        pyc = compile(o.getvalue(), '<string>', 'exec')
        exec pyc in frame

        # Fetch the base_class and form class based on their type in the xml from design
        form_class = frame['Ui_{0}'.format(form_class)]
        base_class = eval('QtGui.{0}'.format(widget_class))

    return form_class, base_class
```

I changed all instances of PySide to PySide2, shiboken to shiboken2 (another change in maya 2017), and pysideuic to pyside2uic. When testing the script, I got the error

```
 Error: line 1: AttributeError: file <string> line 1: 'module' object has no attribute 'QMainWindow' #
```

(line 1 refers to the line in another script:

```
from JUM.core.loadUIFile import get_maya_window, load_ui_type
```

which calls this file)

After a look through the Qt5 documentation, I determined that QMainWindow is now a part of QtWidgets, contained in PyQt5, rather than QtGui so I substituted that as well. Currently the script code is

```
import shiboken2
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI
from cStringIO import StringIO
import pyside2uic
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

def get_maya_window():

    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if ptr is not None:
        return shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(ptr), QtWidgets.QMainWindow)

def load_ui_type(ui_file):

    parsed = xml.parse(ui_file)
    widget_class = parsed.find('widget').get('class')
    form_class = parsed.find('class').text
    with open(ui_file,'r') as f:
        o = StringIO()
        frame = {}

        pyside2uic.compileUi(f, o, indent = 0)
        pyc = compile(o.getvalue(), '<string>', 'exec')
        exec pyc in frame

        # Fetch the base_class and form class based on their type in the xml from design
        form_class = frame['Ui_{0}'.format(form_class)]
        base_class = eval('QtWidgets.{0}'.format(widget_class))

    return form_class, base_class
```

Yet I am still getting the exact same error, so I think something is wrong with my module importing. Can anyone with knowledge of Qt5 in python chime in?

Comment: Surely you need to import from PySide2, not PyQt5?

Comment: @ekhumoro I have tried that too, with the exact same result.

Comment: You could start by manually throwing out all that is not necessary for the error to appear.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer would be this. `QTWidgets` not `QTGui`. In Pyside2 not only do you import shiboken2 and wrapinstance2 but everything good has gone into `QTWidgets`.

```
def get_maya_window():

    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if ptr is not None:
        return shiboken2.wrapInstance2(long(ptr), QtWidgets.QWidget)
```